# Optimal resolution for image proccessing (android)

Tags: android, image, opencv

Suppose i have an image with 4k or FullHD dimensions with large size in byte.
image processing on this image is a big challenge on Android operating system 
**We want to reduce the image dimensions and get max dimension based on memory and processing resources on device.**How can i do this?

thank you.

Comment: check this ref : https://github.com/svenkapudija/Android-ImageResizer

Comment: how to get max dimension based on memory and processing resources on device in my problem